# Dialog.show code returning badtoken error

Tags: android, dialog

I built a budgeting tracker to keep track of my expenses.

I have a dialog popup option at some  parts in the app, these were working fine until I upgraded android studio.

Now I am getting an error at the point where the dialog.show code runs, it has something to do with the way the window is instantiated, can any body help?

Below are the code snippets

```
   private void checkforexbase() throws IOException {
    String pathcat=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/"+appfolder+"/";
    File file=new File(pathcat+"forex.txt");
if(file.exists())Toast.makeText(ctx,"Base set",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    else {
Locale loc = Locale.getDefault();
Currency currency = Currency.getInstance(loc);
final String currentcurr=currency.getCurrencyCode().toString();
WindowManager windowManager;
int layoutParams=WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_TOAST;

final Dialog forexch =new Dialog(ctx);//-> dialog initiated

View view= View.inflate(ctx,R.layout.forxchoose,null);
view.inflate(ctx,R.layout.forxchoose,null);
forexch.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
//forexch.getWindow().setType(Window.FEATURE_CONTENT_TRANSITIONS);
forexch.getWindow().setLayout(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
TextView currtex=(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.currencytex);
forexch.setContentView(view);
 final Spinner spinner = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.forexsp);
final ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = 
ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(ctx,
        R.array.forexlis, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new 
AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
     public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, 
int i, long l) {
if(forxspinfirstrun==true)forexch.dismiss();
        else forxspinfirstrun=true;
        String array[]     = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.forexlis);
        basecurr=array[i].toString();
        forcurr=basecurr;
        try {
            writecurrencybase();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //Toast.makeText(ctx, array[i].toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
        }
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {
        forxspinfirstrun=false;
        //Toast.makeText(ctx,"Select a currency",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return;
    }
});
currtex.setText(currentcurr);
final Button buttonok=(Button)view.findViewById(R.id.buttonokforx);
final Button buttonchange=(Button)view.findViewById(R.id.buttonchangeforx);
  buttonok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        basecurr=currentcurr;
      //Toast.makeText(ctx,"Base currency set",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        forexch.dismiss();
        try {
            writecurrencybase();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


});
buttonchange.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
buttonok.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        buttonchange.setOnClickListener(null);
        spinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.select_dialog_multichoice);
          adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.forexspinlay);
          spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

    }
});
forexch.show();//->this is the crash point

}
  }
```

this is the error in logcat:

```
Process: com.spendo.sam.spendo, PID: 10874
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.spendo.sam.spendo/com.spendo.sam.spendo.mainscreen}: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not valid; is your activity running?              ---> ?_?

   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2817)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
 Caused by: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not valid; is your activity running?
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:765)
        at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:356)
        at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:92)
        at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:330)
        at com.spendo.sam.spendo.mainscreen.checkforexbase(mainscreen.java:427)
```

I am guessing there is a better way to implement a dialog .
The function basically checks if this is the first time the app has started and if so pops up a dialog to select a base currency

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
forexch.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT);
```

and use this permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
```

And use application context while initializing dialog

```
final Dialog forexch =new Dialog(getApplicationContext());//-> dialog initiated
```

Comment: that does not work ,, It was working earlier until I updated android studio,  this is the error -> ,java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.spendo.sam.spendo/com.spendo.sam.spendo.mainscreen}: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window android.view.ViewRootImpl$W@c63bde6 -- permission denied for window type 2003